# I have defined the ordered tree like this but it was not accepted by teacher, what is the formal definition?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

that is what I have defined "***An Ordered Tree is a form of a rooted tree with a specific order of its nodes. Started from the root element the smaller number is on the left side and the higher number on the right side.*** "

but the teacher told me ***"Again, use of ordered trees are mixed here with their simple definition. Do not mix it"***

I want the mathematical definition of ordered tree which is cite-able in paper.
how can I define it?

Comment: Note that "a specific order" is not very specific. Also, there is not really a left and right side. Especially when your tree could be infinite, there might not even be a left or right element amongst the children. Finally, you talk about smaller and larger, but the whole point of defining the order is to define what "smaller" and "larger" mean

Comment: @Vsotvep you are right, what about this definition : An ordered tree is a rooted tree together with a partial order ⪯ on the set of vertices by which vertices with same parent are comparable.If in an ordered tree nodes u,v have common parent, we say u is to the left of v (and v is to the right of u) if u≺v.

Comment: That's a copy of the answer below. Do you understand the definition? I personally prefer defining the partial order such that vertices are comparable if and only if they are children of the same node (what's the difference?)

Comment: Another thing, with ordered trees, it is perhaps more useful to think in family terms as well: instead of talking about left and right children, it is perhaps more intuitive to talk about younger and older children.

Comment: @Vsotvep I completely understand it, it's simple, you mean the comparisons can happen locally, and you can not compare it with another node some where else in the tree...  which means only when we have the same parent. and by younger, how should I define "younger" and "older"?

Comment: Good! You define child $a$ to be younger than $b$ if $a\prec b$, or as you say, $a$ is left of $b$. It fits with the family theme occurring with mathematical tree jargon. The nice thing about restricting the definition as I prefer, is that if there is an isomorphism between two ordered trees in the ordered tree sense, then this automatically is an isomorphism for the parent-child relation and an isomorphism for the partial order between siblings.

Answer (score 1):

How about

> An *ordered tree* is a rooted tree with a total order on the set of children for each node

or

> An *ordered tree* is a rooted tree together with a partial order $\preceq$ on the set of vertices by which vertices with same parent are comparable.

?

Augmented by

> If in an ordered tree nodes $u,v$ have common parent,  we say $u$ is *to the left* of $v$ (and $v$ is *to the right* of $u$) if $u\prec v$.